# Why text next to plot appears on the next page?

Tags: pdftex

I'm using latex for the first time and i was trying this code but it's not working perfectly.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}

\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth] {delta_ew_vs_ew.pdf}
   \caption{} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{delta_ew_by_ew_vs_ew.pdf}
   \caption{}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry

\newgeometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm}
In, fig.1 we compared vibration of produced by a revolving body with time
```

After the plot is done, i want to go back to the universal geometry that i had defined in the beginning of the document but the text that i'm putting after the plot goes to the next page instead of being just below the plot.

How can i solve this issue??

[image]
[image]

Comment: `newgeometry` forces a page break so what you describe is what is expected, but why use `\newgemetry` at all? It may have some specialist uses but in 30 years of using latex I've never needed it so I'm surprised to see it (or `[H]`) used in what you say is your first document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suspect that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

for this is handy the package `changepage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=3.5cm,
                    vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-15mm}{-15mm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth] {delta_ew_vs_ew.pdf}
   \caption{}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delta_ew_by_ew_vs_ew.pdf}
   \caption{}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
In, fig.1 we compared vibration of produced by a revolving body with time
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked but the plots still have the same margins. why so?

Comment: @astroluv, is difficult to say anything with out seeing your plots. maybe your images contain white space around image.

Comment: Image still have the same margin and i don't understand why. wait i'll upload them.

Comment: Hey, i've uploaded the picture, can you check it out please?

Comment: i suppose, that images are generated by some (non)latex program. make the following test: encpsulte them in `\fbox`: `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delta_ew_by_ew_vs_ew.pdf}}` and see, if there is white space between frame and image. if it is, than you need to trim this space some how (the best with proper adjustment of the program, which was generated these pictures.